# Python Mocking - How to store function arguments to a mocked function in the mock that is returned?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Consider two explicit MagicMocks, such that one is used to create new mock instances by calling a method with arguments, and these mocks in turn are passed to the other mock's method as arguments:

```
In [1]: from unittest.mock import MagicMock

In [2]: foo = MagicMock()

In [3]: bar = MagicMock()

In [4]: a = foo.a(1, 2)

In [5]: b = foo.b(3, 4)

In [6]: bar.func(a, b)
Out[6]: <MagicMock name='mock.func()' id='140383162348976'>

In [7]: bar.method_calls
Out[7]: [call.func(<MagicMock name='mock.a()' id='140383164249232'>, <MagicMock name='mock.b()' id='140383164248848'>)]
```

Note that the `bar.method_calls` list contains calls to the functions `.a` and `.b`, but the parameters that were passed to those functions are missing. From what I can tell, they aren't recorded in `bar` at all. They can be found in `foo`:

```
In [8]: foo.method_calls
Out[8]: [call.a(1, 2), call.b(3, 4)]
```

But they are decoupled from their use as parameters to `bar.func`, thus unusable as a check that `bar.func` was called correctly in anything but the most trivial case (for instance, there may be many calls to `foo.a` unrelated to the `bar.func` call).

At first, I expected that the new mocks `a` and `b` would store the parameters passed, but in fact they do not, because `foo.a(...)` returns a new MagicMock that happens to have the name `mock.a()`, but call and arguments are recorded by `foo`. `a` does not store them. Same with `b`. Therefore when `bar.func(a, b)` is called, the arguments for `a` and `b` are not present, nor stored in `bar`.

Can the `foo` mock be configured in some way to create new MagicMock instances that record the parameters passed to its `.a` and `.b` methods? If not, can the code be refactored to capture the full call history in `bar`? Ideally lines 4 - 6 are *not* test code, and should remain unaware of any mocking.

EDIT: to be clear, my goal is to be able to test that the function `bar.func` was called with parameters `foo.a(1, 2)` and `foo.b(3, 4)`. This seems to be fundamentally different from testing that the function `func` was called with parameters `(1, 2)` and `(3, 4)` due to the extra indirection of `bar.` and `foo.`.

---

*(The comment below was ultimately addressed in the final accepted answer, but I leave it here for posterity)*

EDIT2: [blhsing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6890912/blhsing) has offered a solution involving a subclass of `MagicMock` that mostly works. However there's one case that fails:

```
class TraceableMock(MagicMock):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        child_mock = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        child_mock.attach_mock(self, 'parent_mock')
        return child_mock

foo = TraceableMock()
bar = MagicMock()
a = foo.a(1, 2)
a2 = foo.b(5, 6)  # extra call to foo.a, unrelated to the upcoming bar.func() call
b = foo.b(3, 4)
bar.func(a, b)
print(bar.func.call_args.args[0].parent_mock.mock_calls)
print(bar.func.call_args.args[1].parent_mock.mock_calls)
print(bar.func.call_args.args[0].parent_mock.mock_calls == [call(1, 2)])
```

This outputs:

```
[call(1, 2), call(5, 6)]
[call(3, 4)]
False
```

I think this is because the Mock created for `foo.a` is reused, and therefore records an additional call. I can test for this:

```
assert call(1, 2) in bar.func.call_args.args[0].parent_mock.mock_calls
```

But unfortunately this does not guarantee that the `call(1, 2)` was actually one of the parameters to `bar.func()`.

I could impose a condition that `foo.a` and `foo.b` are each only called *once*, but this is too strict, because there is no reason why these functions cannot be called multiple times, and it's only the call to `bar.func`, and its parameters, that I care about in this case.

In the context of my overall problem, I'm beginning to wonder if perhaps a better is to patch in smart, custom wrapper objects, able to log their own calls, rather than trying to use Mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that as it is, a child `Mock` object returned by making a call to a `Mock` object does not have any linkage back to the `Mock` object that created it, thus losing the record of the call from the standpoint of the child object.

You can work around the lack of such a linkage by creating your own subclass of `Mock` with a wrapper `__call__` method that returns a `Mock` object cloned from the original returning `Mock` object, with last the `call` object of the parent `Mock`, as well as the parent `Mock` object itself, stored as additional attributes:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call

class TraceableMock(MagicMock):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        child_mock = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(child_mock, TraceableMock):
            mock = TraceableMock()
            mock.__dict__ = child_mock.__dict__.copy()
            mock.created_from = self.mock_calls[-1]
            mock.attach_mock(self, 'parent_mock')            
            return mock
        return child_mock

foo = TraceableMock()
bar = MagicMock()
a = foo.a(1, 2)
a2 = foo.a(5, 6)
b = foo.b(3, 4)
c = foo(7, 8)
bar.func(a, b)

print(bar.func.call_args.args[0].created_from)
print(bar.func.call_args.args[1].created_from)
print(c.created_from)
print(bar.func.call_args.args[0].created_from == call(1, 2))
print(bar.func.call_args.args[0].parent_mock is foo.a)
```

This outputs:

```
call(1, 2)
call(3, 4)
call(7, 8)
True
True
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/CalculatingIllCustomization